# Windows Phone 8 emulator error on debugging

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm working on Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin. Everytime I start debugging my Xamarin.Forms App on the Windows Phone 8 Emulator I get the errormessage:
"The application could not be started to debugg. Be sure that the target device screen is unlocked and the application is installed". But the screen is unlocked and if I take a look into the Emulator the App is installed, but I have to click on it to start it. I already removed the app and installed it new, but it's the same problem. Also checked the Config Manager the Checkboxes for Windows Phone to start and debugg is checked. 
Any idea for this problem?

Comment: if you see app already installed on emulator , then uninstall first and then try again.

Comment: already tried, did not work

Comment: so, you need to to uninstall your emulator first and then install it again, if you get your solution from another pc or from internet this problem may be same, or debug your app on physical device instead